# All vectors $(a, b, c, d)\in K^4$ are described by a 2×2-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am currently taking a course in linear algebra and for the first time in my life I will probably fail a maths test. Since there are about 100 theorems in my linear algebra book and each theorem has an average of 10 rules and some theorems use each other, it gets pretty tough. I decided to try to understand the material instead of memorizing every rule.

When watching 3blue1brown's video entitled "matrix multiplication  as composition | Essence of linear algebra, chapter 4" He describes the following matrix multiplication

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ae+bg&af+bh\\ce+dg&cf+dh\end{bmatrix}
$$

I understand the rule and can memorize it... however it makes no sense to me. How my professor and my book describes matrices is, not exactly but basically, as follows:

Matrices (plural of matrix) are made up of equations. For example:
$$
2x+3y+6z\\
4x+1y+5z
$$

which is the same as:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&3&6\\4&1&5\end{bmatrix}
$$

Meaning the first column is the x value for each equation, the second column contains all the y values, and so on.

I would think that only the x values of a matrix could affect the x values of another matrix. However in the first example the first element in the matrix $ae+bg$ is a contradiction to my assumption in that $bg$ is the y value of one equation times the x value of another equation.

I can memorize the rule but I have no way of visualizing it (however 3blue1brown's video did a great job of visualizing what he described it makes not sense. Is the first elements of the first column, going doing the rows, x and y? I thought that the first row was an equation and that x and y is the two elements of the row.) nor a logical explanation as to why we derived this method. Can anyone guide me further?

P.S
English isn't my first language so if I drifted of in a nonsensical way somewhere, please comment or propose an edit and I'll change it as soon as I can!

Edit:
I am getting down votes, how can I improve my question? The ways I can improve it by myself is limited because I have limited knowledge.

Comment: Title question: All vectors $(a,b,c,d)\in K^4$ are described by a $2\times 2$-matrix.

Comment: I am getting down voted, can anybody guide me so that I know how to better phrase this question?

Comment: @linker I would suggest a title related to matrix multiplication as the composition of linear maps. Proving $2 \times 2$ matrices form a vector space doesn't involved matrix multiplication at all.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I changed the title to the one Dietrich suggested. I do not understand it but it seems math-y, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking of the matrix as just the expressions $2x+3y+6z$ and $4x+y+5z$, think of it as the map/function
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \binom{2x+3y+6z}{4x+y+5z} $$
Then matrix multiplication is composition of these maps.
If you first do $\begin{pmatrix} e&f\\g&h\end{pmatrix}$, you get
$$ \binom{x}{y} \mapsto \binom{ex+fy}{gx+hy} = \binom{x'}{y'} $$
Now apply the second matrix to $x'$ and $y'$:
$$ \binom{x'}{y'} \mapsto \binom{ax'+by'}{cx'+dy'} $$
Substitute in the expressions $x'=ex+fy$ and $y'=gx+hy$ to get $$\binom{a(ex+fy)+b(gx+hy)}{c(ex+fy)+d(gx+hy)} = \binom{(ae+bg)x+(af+bh)y}{(ce+dg)x+(cf+dh)y} $$
Notice that this is the same as applying the product matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}ae+bg & af+bh \\ ce+dg & cf+dh \end{pmatrix} $$
directly to $\binom{x}{y}$.

Comment: I am struggling to truly feel and understand the first thing you did with the (x y z) pointing arrow to the matrix. This feels really unintuitive to me... Does it mean that for every x, y and z they map to the matrix? I can't really put it into words.

Comment: The thing after the arrow is not a matrix, just a vector (with two components). The $x$-component is $2x+3y+6z$, and the $y$-component is $4x+y+5z$. It is a function $\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^2$, and the vector on the right (after the arrow) means the result of applying the function to $(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: When you say "it is a function $R^3 \to R^2$, do you mean that its a three dimensional vector that draws something on $R^2$ (aka the regular xy-plane)? If so, what would be a good way to visualize this? Can I visualize the vector in wolfram alpha? In MatLab?

Comment: It is a function $f(x,y,z)$ that takes three numbers as inputs, and the ouput is a vector in the $xy$-plane. If you plug in $x,y,z$, you get the vector $(2x+3y+6z, \, 4x+y+5z)$. For instance, $f(1,1,1) = (11, 10)$. I don't know a good way to visualize it. In general, linear maps $\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^m$ are hard or impossible to visualize if $n$ and $m$ are bigger than 2 or 3.

Comment: this is my issue with linear algebra. I learn a bit then I have a really difficult time because there is nothing in my head. There is nothing to visualize, just calculating matrices that seems to lead to only math and nothing practical. I love mathematics because of its many implication and how I can see what happens in a graph, I cannot do that with Linear Algebra. Am I in the wrong here? Is there a way to visualize most of linear algebra or am I correct about my experience that it is heavy theory and little tangible everyday physical implications?

Comment: The "physical implications" depends on the context, and what the linear equations and matrices represent. It could be different in different situations. But your original question seemd to be about theory, and not specific applications.

Comment: Well I am asking what is what, Is the first column $x_1$ and $x_2$ or is it $x, y$? Is every row an equation? A vector? $x$ and $y$? What is what? Also are there cases where it is not? It seems that linear algebra is full of contradictions, special cases, multiple synonyms for the same thing, and so on. Very much unstructured. That is why I am asking because I cannot find a good definition and proof of what a matrix truly is.

Comment: Take a look at the other answer, posted by @CyclotomicField. It is similar to my answer, but instead of using the "arrow" notation, they more explicitly write it in terms of multiplying the matrix by a vector.

Answer (score 1):

I find it useful to keep the  variables around when setting up the matrix multiplication. For for example I would write $$\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 &6\\4 & 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2x+3y+6z\\
4x+1y+5z\end{pmatrix}$$ and all we've done here is add some braces around the equations but otherwise this is the same. Now lets say I have some other linear equations that define the system given by $$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\-2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-u + v\\-2u + v\end{pmatrix}$$

and say we want to compose these two maps by first applying one then the other. We could do this by substitution using that $u=2x+3y+6z$ and $v=4x+y + 5z$ so apply both maps using the variables $x,y$ and $z$ directly. After doing this several times you quickly begin to see some patterns. One of them is that you're working with the coefficients, not the variables. Secondly, the dot product is used over and over again to calculate each new coeffecient. This is the motivation for defining matrix multiplication as it is. We can set it up as $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 &6\\4 & 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

and we can use matrix multiplication to calculate that $$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 &6\\4 & 1 & 5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 &-2& -1 \\ 0 & -5& -7 \end{pmatrix}$$

This is exactly the same result as the substitution method would yield.